# How to write to first line of a text file in dos

Tags: windows, dos

I want to write to first line of an existing text file which has plenty of lines in it. I just wanted to add one line at the starting of the file.

Comment: There's no way to insert at the start of a file. YOu'll have to create a new file, write your new line, then copy the original file's contents after that.

Comment: @MarcB: who says that this is not the solution the OP is looking for?

Comment: Ohhh....there is no way?? It is surprising to me. Anyway thanks Marc.

Comment: @user1614862: nonsense, its perfectly possible the way Marc B described it, read the answers at the link of Howard Renollet.

Comment: I understand that, I was just assuming there may be a direct solution with some flag.

Comment: But copying files from one to another is becoming an overhead, because my files are very huge and they are present at the network location.  Any better solution for this?