# How to write in the first line of a text file with cmd?

Tags: file, powershell, cmd, echo

I searched but I did not find the answer I want.

I have an existing file that contains several lines and I want to write a line that will now be the first line.

Example : `echo toto >> file.txt` written at the end of the file, I want to write it at the beginning.

Only with cmd / powershell (no Cygwin or other)

Any ideas ?

Thank you :)

Comment: can u provide the code that u tried to check

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20107814/how-to-write-to-first-line-of-a-text-file-in-dos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In DOS/CMD:

```
echo "toto" > TempNewFile.txt
type file.txt >> TempNewFile.txt
type TempNewFile.txt > file.txt
del TempNewFile.txt
```

In PowerShell

```
@("toto") + (Get-Content file.txt) | Set-Content file.txt
```

Comment: Yes it works and I use that, but there is no special order or argument for the echo command?

Comment: @Carlinto, what do you mean by no special order?

Comment: I want say "special command" sorry :p

Comment: Ah. Not that I'm aware of, sorry.